# Combining Data from class into a DataTable using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like so

```
class Person(){
  int Id;
  string Name;
  string SomePersonalInfo;
}
```

and a datatable with columns being Id, Name, and SomePersonalInfo. I also have a collection housing data in a List.

```
List<Person> = new Id = 1, Name = "So So"
List<Person> = new Id = 1, SomePersonalInfo= "Something"
```

I am trying to use linq so I dont  have multiple for each statements to add Name and SomePersonalInfo in the datatable or making unnessary steps like keep getting the datarow. ANy suggestions

Comment: So you want to have a `DataTable` from the `List<Person>` or vice-versa? If you already have a strongly typed list, why do you want to have  a loosely typed `DataTable` at all?

Comment: no I already have the datatable I am just trying to update the datatable from the collection

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a strongly typed list, why do you want to have  a loosely typed `DataTable` at all? Also, there is no good way to create a `DataTable` via LINQ-query without having `DataRow`s.

Therefore i would simply use a loop which is readable and efficient:

```
foreach(Person p in persons)
    tblPerson.Rows.Add(p.Id, p.Name, p.SomePersonalInfo);
```

**Update** acc. comment:

> no I already have the datatable I am just trying to update the
>   datatable from the collection

Then you have to find the intersection first, use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var inBoth = from p in persons
             join row in tblPersons.AsEnumerable()
             on p.Id equals row.Field<int>("Id")
             select new { Person = p, Row = row };

foreach(var b in inBoth)
{
    b.Row.SetField("Name", b.Person.Name);
    b.Row.SetField("SomePersonalInfo", b.Person.SomePersonalInfo);
}
```